# Displaying a spatio-temporal spectrum with imshow: what order are the frequencies in after taking an FFT down columns?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fft, imshow

---------- `Summary` ----------

If I have 2D data `psi_hat_kxt` and I take its FFT down columns and FFT-shift the result, `np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(psi_hat_kxt, axis=0))`, where are the negative frequencies located? Shouldn't they be in the top half of the resulting array? If so, when I plot the result (squared element-wise to get real data) using `imshow`, is there an implicit up-down flip somewhere?

---------- `Detailed` ----------

I have a simulation that evolves a field in spatial Fourier space (k-space) and I want to show the frequency content for each k. That is to say, I want to plot the [spatio-temporal spectrum](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.06666.pdf), a.k.a. k-omega plot, by taking the FFT in the time direction, squaring, and plotting. I am doing all this in NumPy,

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# other code that assigns variables like Nt, Nx, Deltat, dx etc.
```

My data [*Edit*: which is complex-valued] is arranged as rows containing the k-space data, and time evolves moving down each row. I read this in from an external binary file and then reshape:

```
fname = open('../output/ky0slices.bin','rb')
psi_hat_kxt_vec = np.fromfile(fname, dtype=np.complex_)
fname.close()
psi_hat_kxt  = np.reshape(psi_hat_kxt_vec , (Nt,Nx))
```

I then do the FFT down the columns, shift, and square to get a real number:

```
komega_spec = np.abs( np.fft.fftshift (np.fft.fft(psi_hat_kxt, axis=0)) )**2.0
```

Finally I plot using imshow:

```
om_ax = 2*np.pi * np.fft.fftshift( np.fft.fftfreq(Nt,d=Deltat) )
k_ax  = 2*np.pi * np.fft.fftshift( np.fft.fftfreq(Nx,d=dx) )
log_komega_spec = np.log(komega_spec)

extnt=[k_ax[0], k_ax[-1] , om_ax[0], om_ax[-1] ]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = plt.imshow(log_komega_spec, extent=extnt , aspect='auto')
```

In the end I get an image that looks correct,
[image: correctly oriented k-omega plot]

*But I don't understand why it is actually correct.*

Namely, from reading the docs I thought that after the `fftshift`, the negative temporal frequencies should have their Fourier coefficients in the top rows of the fft data, i.e. `komega_spec[0,:]` should contain a row with all the Fourier coefficients corresponding to frequency `-Nt/2`.

But from the shape of the plot it appears that this row corresponds to the positive frequency `Nt/2-1`. (It seems this way because the parabola is convex, as it should be for physical reasons, please ignore the omega-axis ticks as they are controlled by `extnt`.)

Is `imshow` maybe doing an implicit `flipud`?

In short: why does it seem that the top half of `komega_spec` contains the positive frequency data?

Comment: You’re mixing up the dimensions. You computed the FFT along the rows. I can tell because they are symmetric, and I’m assuming your input data was real-valued.

Comment: Thanks Cris. The input data is complex. I thought I was taking the FFT along the rows, but checking the documentation, and examples elsewhere, the `axis=0` argument definitely takes the FFT down the columns. 

I am expecting this kind of parabola anyway because the spectrum should be concentrated around the omega=k^2 curve. This makes me think I'm doing the FFT correctly, but I can't figure out why the parabola is the correct way up using the code I provided.

Comment: It does look like the `extent` property sets the origin in the bottom left -- note how your omega axis increases upwards. Setting `origin` to `'upper'` should fix that. https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html

Comment: Weird. Reading the words in the tutorial you shared, it seems that it is indeed the `extent` kwarg that flips it. But weirdly I can't replicate the behaviour shown in the plots in that link. Namely my plot is identical to my original post if I set `orign='upper'`, but flipped upside down if I set `origin='lower'`, when I would expect the opposite if I follow the tutorial link. So I'm still confused!

Comment: Indeed, that is strange. Either you have some bit of code you don't show where you flip the axis, or found a bug in Matplotlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that we need to make the transformation `omega -> - omega` to convert between the physical `omega = k^2` of the dispersion relation
(in the sense that we expand the function in plane waves
`psi(x,t) = Sum psi_hat(k, omega) * exp[i(k*x-omega*t)]`
)
and the `omega` that is the argument of what the FFT spits out
(in the sense that the FFT calculates
`F(omega) = Sum f(t) * exp[ +i(omega*t) ]`

So the physical dispersion relation should indeed show up in the "negative frequencies" as far as the FFT is concerned..

Answer (score 0):

Yes..  imshow is doing an implicit flipud. Try following and the problem should be resolved:

```
im = plt.imshow(np.flipud(log_komega_spec), extent=extnt , aspect='auto')
```